# Refresh contents of SD Card on Android devices?

Tags: gratis, android, memory-card

Storing files on the SC card on Android causes the problem that the files are only visible on the PC after restarting the phone. I want to avoid to restart always the phone after I store a new file with an app in the SD card space. Does anyone know an app which avoids this problem?

The app should run on Android 4.3 or less, be free, easy-to-use and automatically run in background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Rescan SD Card!](http://www.appbrain.com/app/rescan-sd-card/com.uberullu.rescansd)** is what I use on my devices, and I'm pretty satisfied with it. Just re-checked the details on the app's page, and see it was even updated to work with Kitkat (Android 4.4; there have been changes applied to that Android version which rendered most Rescan apps inoperable).

How does this app match your requirements?

- *free:* It comes at no cost. Ad-free as well (no ad-module contained)
- *easy to use:* Well, press the button (ahem, icon; i.e. start the app) and there it goes.
- *automatically run in background:* once started, it does exactly that. No nasty foreground "window" displaying fancy things. Just start it, and it notifies you (toast) once it's done.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (source: Google Play; click to enlarge)</sup>